# Build Excel VSTO Add-In using VS (Visual Studio) Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm looking to develop a VSTO Add-In for Excel as deploying my Add-In made via Office-JS framework just simply failed via M365 Admin Center.

But, I don't want to use Visual Studio, can I develop a VSTO Add-In using only Visual Studio Code? I can certainly get my hands on a template generated by VS and then look at setting that up in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code doesn't provide any tools or extensions for VSTO add-ins. VSCode is used for .net core projects while VSTO add-ins are based on .net framework only. Note, you can download the Community edition where you can build VSTO add-ins.

However, Visual Studio is not a requirement for building any kind of software. The question is how convenient the process will be without it :)

Comment: Community edition is not an option, you say visual studio isn't a requirement but how can I work on VSTO Add-In without it?

Comment: Like with any other .net application.